# Java File IO vs Local database

Tags: java, database, file-io

I am working on a project that involves parsing through a LARGE amount of data rapidly. Currently this data is on disk and broken down into a directory hierarchy:

```
(Folder: DataSource) -> (Files: Day1, Day2, Day3...Day1000...)
(Folder: DataSource2) -> (Files: Day1, Day2, Day3...Day1000...) 
...
(Folder: DataSource1000) -> ...
...
```

Each Day file consists of entries that need to be accessed very quickly.

My initial plans were to use traditional FileIO in java to access these files, but upon further reading, I began to fear that this might be too slow.

In short, what is the fastest way I can selectively load entries from my filesystem from varying DataSources and Days?

Comment: Keep using file access but instead use [Java NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)

Comment: We don't really have enough information here. Do you *only* need to query by data source and day? Do you then load the whole file? If so, using the file system as-is may make sense. If there's any more complexity, the database may well help a lot.

Comment: Please first test and profile your code before asking for performance hints. Try using multiple threads could help...

Comment: @JonSkeet - A query would consist of source, day, and position in file (each entry in a file is the same length, so I can immediately seek to given entries). There is no writing to the files, only reading. Ideally, I don't read the whole file, I just seek to parts of it and cherry-pick entries.

Comment: @UwePlonus - could you expand on your multithreading approach? I've head before that it is not performant to thread FileIO.

Comment: @ChrisGrimm you can map the files into memory with `FileChannel`, the bonus is that these mappings don't take any burden on the heap other than the objects to handle these mappings. You should have a go at that. The OS will do the caching for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue could be solved both ways but it depends on few factors

**go for FileIO.**

1. if the volume is **< millons of rows**
2. if your dont do a complicated query like Jon Skeet said
3. if your referance for fetching the row is by using hte Folder Name: "DataSource" as the key

**go for DB**

1. if you see your program reading **through millions of records**
2. you can do complicated selection, even multiple rows using a single select.
3. if you have knowledge of creating a basic table structure for DB

Comment: Theoretically, I shouldn't have to access all of the data at once, and I know exactly where a given entry is in a File. Should I be concerned about the number of files I may have open? It will not be uncommon that my program will need to open several thousand of these files in a short span of time.

Comment: if you know exactly where the data is, you may not need a DB. I was expecting you to read all the content line by line or as a buffer and do a check.

Comment: Reading lines would be far too slow. When I say I know exactly where the data is, I know where entries in the file are. Each entry is timestamped and organized chronologically in the file. However, data is arriving frequently enough that multiple entries in the file may have the same timestamp. Meaning I may have to do a bit of seeking. I am really trying to squeeze every bit of performance I can out of this program. Understanding this, do you still think I don't need a database?

Comment: you could give a try for mySql and compare performance. When data increases further, the split of you data from business logic will help in giving a better performance in Future.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on architecture you are using you can implement different ways of caching, in the Jboss there is a built-in Jboss Caching, there are also third party opensource software that lets utilizes caching, like Redis, or EhCache depending on your needs. Basically Caching stores objects in their memory, some are passivated/activated upon demand, when memory is exhausted it is stored as a physical IO file, which are also easily activated marshalled by the caching mechanism. It lowers the database connectivity held by your program. There are other caches but here are some of them that I've worked with:

- Jboss:http://www.jboss.org/jbosscache/
- Redis:http://redis.io/
- EhCache:http://ehcache.org/

Comment: How performant are these caching solutions with very large amounts of data? The dataset I am working with is currently growing by approximately 800MB daily.

Comment: This will also depend on the machine you will be using and how you will optimize the caching software When I was using the built in jboss cache, we had about 180,000 objects being cross referenced to 500,000 - 1,000,000 users. As caching can be an external part of the system, you can set different memory allocations for such depending on your need.

Comment: Okay, sounds reasonable, thanks a lot for the links and advice!

Answer (score 0):

> what is the fastest way I can selectively load entries from my filesystem from varying DataSources and Days?

*selectively* means filtering, so my answer is a localhost database. Generally speaking if you filter, sort, paginate or extract distinct records from a large number of records, it's hard to beat a localhost SQL server. You get a query optimizer (nobody does that Java), a cache (which requires effort in Java, especially the invalidation), database indexes (have not seen that being done in Java either) etc. It's possible to implement these things manually, but then your are writing a database in Java.

On top of this you gain access to higher level SQL functions like window aggegrates etc., so in most cases there is no need to post-process data in Java.