# IO vs Database: Which is faster?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, io, bufferedreader

Imagine I have 1GB sized txt file. In my Java program, I am reading this "line by line" using `BufferedReader`.

Imagine I also have a `MySQL` database which includes each line of the 1GB file as a new row. I am reading this "row by row" inside my Java program.

Now, which operation is faster in this situation, reading the file or Database? Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17141286/931982

Comment: Performance isn't the only consideration. You also need to consider architecture, points of failure, ... For example, *why* do you have the same data in two places? What are the risks of them getting out of sync? What are the consequences?

Comment: There is the problem that the relational model has no notion of order; if you need to access, say, a range of lines, you'll have to add supplementary information into the database just for that (and probably indexed too)

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader is faster. But the explanation is a bit complexer.

In case the database is warmed up (running a while) much is taken in memory. In that case the database might be faster, running on the same machine. But warming up would require same queries, which is not the case. That is: once the MySQL has to read everything first in memory. Another advantage of the database would be that the database could already read following records while you are at one `resultSet.next()` step. I do not know whether MySQL JDBC is that clever.

On the negative side, a connection has to be made, and data marshalled.

With a BufferedReader you still could do your line processing time is a separate thread 
(or even more threads), so MySQL has no real (or hypotethical)  advantage.